# Why doesn't my Users/myname/go folder exist?

Tags: go, goland

When I type in go env it shows me the path Users/myname/go

I can use go from the terminal, I can even run a go file... When I open GoLand it says GOPATH is empty.  I can't even set my go path there because I can't find the folder to select on.  I try to cd into the directory from Users/myname and It still doesn't work.  I am extremely confused here.

I have added both of these to my bash_profile even though I read it isn't necessary anymore.

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
```

What is going on? Why don't I have this folder?

EDIT: I downloaded it from here https://golang.org/dl/ for mac

Comment: So you set GOPATH to $HOME/go (even though it's the default value, I think), but did you create that dir?

Comment: If you run `which go`, what does it say?

Comment: /usr/local/go/bin/go . Is that the path I should use

Comment: Well, there you go. Just create the dir and it'll hopefully just work.

Comment: Thank you.  I also saw in the docs the package should put the /usr/local/go/bin directory in your PATH environment variable. You may need to restart any open Terminal sessions for the change to take effect. I guess I thought go env did something different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the folder under /usr/local/go

I should have read this.

Download the package file, open it, and follow the prompts to install the Go tools. The package installs the Go distribution to /usr/local/go.

The package should put the /usr/local/go/bin directory in your PATH environment variable. You may need to restart any open Terminal sessions for the change to take effect.

Edit: also this comment helped as far as the correct command.  "where go"

[Why doesn't my Users/myname/go folder exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56519162/why-doesnt-my-users-myname-go-folder-exist#comment99623450_56519162)

Thanks, leaving up for anyone else as confused as me.